# Why would attempting to plug an audio jack to a USB port make the laptop suddenly shut down?

Tags: usb, motherboard

I often use headphones with my laptop. On its rightmost side there is an audio jack socket and right next to it a USB socket.

I was trying to plug my headphones' audio jack plug to the laptop's audio jack socket while my laptop was operating. However, due to less-than-perfect lighting, I was forced to feel around. Putting trust in my practice, this time I didn't first carefully determined the jack socket's exact whereabouts, but rather, I boldly plugged my headphones where I thought I remembered the jack socket to be.

That was a mistake. I rammed the jack plug right into the USB socket. And I was astonished to my laptop shut down immediately, just like the power was cut off.

Now I understand that a USB socket is a no place for a jack plug, but nevertheless I'm curious. Why did this happen? What mechanism is responsible for that? How possible that tampering with a USB  port can destabilize the whole system?

Comment: This this a security provided by computer electronic components. check USBKill on google.

Answer (score 5):

Shoving a metal cylinder into a jack with multiple conductors, including the main 5VDC and Gnd lines for your computer, is likely to short-out the 5VDC line and cause the computer to malfunction or shut down, yes. Best case scenario is, there is no permanent damage. Worst-case scenario is, you may have damaged the 5V regulator and/or other parts. Time will tell. If the computer starts up and works normally, there was likely no permanent damage.